# Etsy API ListingVariationImage endpoint expects value_id different from known value_id

Tags: python, api, oauth, etsy

I'm stumped. Etsy has a ListingVariationImage endpoint (`/listings/:id/variation-images`) to which one POSTs an array of tuples, `{property_id, value_id, image_id}`.

I want to assign Color: Black to an image, so I post `{property_id=200, value_id=1, image_id=MYID}`. 200 is the property_id for "Primary color", 1 is the value_id for "Black", and MYID is a valid image id. This is what I get in response:

`HTTP 400: variation with property_id 200 and value_id 1 is invalid`

I have tried manually setting the variation-images for this listing in the Etsy UI (Color: Black to my image), then fetching the variation-images from the API. I get back this:

`{property_id=200, value_id=49928889190, image_id=2420286876}`

What on earth is 49928889190? When I fetch the inventory of this listing, that valueId does not show up at all. It's not in the taxonomy node properties for graphic tees (which is what this listing is set to). I can't find it anywhere in the API.

How do I use the Etsy API to assign images to property values using the variation-images endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the details of your listing id using the API endpoint for getAttributes

```
GET /listings/:listing_id/attributes
```

than go into detail for your one specific property 200 with
getAttribute

```
GET /listings/:listing_id/attributes/200
```

https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/propertyvalue

If you have property_id 200 defined, it seems that a value_id 1 is not a defined value yet.

Please update the property as you want to have it.
updateAttribute

```
PUT /listings/:listing_id/attributes/200
```

The Etsy API documentation states in several examples property and value mappings but does not explicitly mention that you have to configure those things first OR (if created via UI) check which IDs were used in your App context.

Comment: This seems like it should be right! But it still doesn't work. I've updated the attribute, and now GET https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/829846826/attributes/200 returns `[{"property_id":200,"property_name":"Primary color","scale_id":null,"scale_name":null,"value_ids":[1,10],"values":["Black","White"]}]`. But trying to set variation-images using {200, 1} still produces the same `variation with property_id 200 and value_id 1 is invalid` error.

Comment: Seems to be related to this predefined "Primary color"... I wouldn't expect support from etsy developers here as you already find things like "Deprecated: May return inaccurate data. Use <blabla> instead.". This will need a workaround with custom properties/values somehow.

Comment: funny enough, i just ran into the EXACT same errors. I am posting `{'variation_images': '[{"property_id": 52047899002, "value_id": 10, "image_id": 2441173670}, {"property_id": 52047899002, "value_id": 1213, "image_id": 2441173856}]'}`

Comment: It looks like the brunt on the investigation is happening in a google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/etsy-api-v2/cJg3TlOB0Y8